# IE7 automatically setting inline style height

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, inline-styles

Here's my deal: 
The boss asked me to fix a page not displaying properly in IE7.

I'm working with a div tag initially set as:

```
<div id="login_content" style="left: 0px; text-align: center;">
```

And so it is rendered in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE9. The issue comes in IE7--somehow the div is cut off when IE7 automagically decides to set the inline style with a height of 8px.

There are no scripts that modify this (as I said, it doesn't get touched in other modern browsers) and upon inspection with IE9 developer tools, it's not inherited from a style sheet. Does anyone know what might cause this behavior?

[image: Screencap of IE7 rendered div in developer tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's running through an external script it's probably an inline style in that. If you post a link we can use inspection tools.

You can use the conditional `<!--[if IE7] code to fix it [endif]-->` to just change how it renders on IE7.

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good fix. If it were up to me we'd just force our users to upgrade, but what can you do?

Comment: The good news is, IE is falling off more each year. It only represents 13% or so of web users as of January 2013.